# How to get date picker in millisecond

Tags: java, android, datepicker

How to get correct month from datepicker in milliseconds?

I tried to get date in milliseconds from datepicker but, It always get wrong month like January

```
mDisplayDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               cal = Calendar.getInstance();
               int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
               int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
               int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
               DatePickerDialog datepick = new DatePickerDialog(AddPostActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth, mDateSetListener, year,month,day);
               datepick.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
               datepick.show();
           }
       });

       mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) { month = month + 1;
               Log.d(TAG, "onDateSet: dd/mm/yyyy: " + day + "/" + month + "/" + year);

               String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

               mDisplayDate.setText(date);
               DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");

               Date outputdate = formatter.parse(date);


               Long dateinmilli = outputdate .getTime() ;

           }
       };
```

Comment: new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy"); the mm should be uppercase = MM. lowercase is for minutes.

Comment: `mm` is minutes, not month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Date and Time Patterns](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Use `MM` for month. Lowercase stands for minutes, while capital M is months.

```
 DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```